# Cygwin g++ does not allow ./file on windows 8

Tags: linux, g++, cygwin

When I compiled a program on cygwin like the following

```
g++ -o helloworld helloworld.cpp
```

An executable helloworld.exe is created. However, I could not execute the program by using

```
./helloworld
```

but instead I need to use

```
./helloworld.exe
```

Is there a way to enable the cygwin to recognize `helloworld` as an executable for the file `helloworld.exe`

Comment: That's expected behavior. You're probably used to CMD doing that, but linux shells require exact names (even casing). So no.

Comment: Sounds like a bug report. Cygwin has always allowed you to omit the .exe in the past.

Comment: @Qix In fact, I could use ./helloworld on my windows 7 machine. I don't know if it is because OS or I missed some configuration step.

Comment: @Qix is wrong. All the executables that are part of Cygwin include the.exe in their names!

Comment: I doubt that this is related to g++. In my experience, Cygwin *does* let you invoke a `helloworld.exe` executable in the current directory either as `./helloworld` or as `./helloworld.exe`. Is there another `helloworld.*` file in the current directory? What *exactly* happens when you type `./helloworld`? (Telling us that you can't do something is far less useful than telling us exactly what happens when you try.)

Comment: @KeithThompson Genius! That's exactly what happened, there is another file named helloworld compiled by gcc. Thank you so much!

Comment: So you have an executable file with no `.exe` suffix? If you have both `helloworld` and `helloworld.exe`, then I *think* that typing `./helloworld` will execute `helloworld.exe`.

Comment: You're right, I stand corrected.

Comment: How are you running cygwin? Using MinTTY or by invoking `bash.exe` from a command prompt?

Comment: For the benefit of future readers, please update your question to indicate exactly what happens when you type `./helloworld` vs. `./helloworld.exe`. If there's an error message, please copy-and-paste it into your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This isn't directly related to g++.

Windows requires executable files (of the kind generated by a compiler, not batch files) to have names with a `.exe` extension; that's how the OS recognizes them as executables.

Cygwin, as you know, implements a POSIX-like layer on top of Windows. POSIX systems (UNIX, Linux, et al) do not require any special suffix for executable files; the OS recognizes a file as executable based on a "magic number" in the file itself and the executable bit in its directory entry.

To bridge this gap, Cygwin treats the `.exe` extension separately. Compilers like g++ generate executable files with the `.exe` suffix, but Cygwin lets you execute a file named `helloworld.exe` by typing either `./helloworld.exe` or `./helloworld`. (This even applies to other operations; `ls -l helloworld` will show you information about `helloworld.exe` -- assuming there's not also a file named just `helloworld`.)

In this case, based in information you've provided in the comments, you apparently have two executable files in your current directory, `helloworld.exe` and `helloworld`.

I'm not 100% sure what Cygwin will do in this case, but the solution is to delete the `helloworld` file and make sure that your executables have the required `.exe` extension. Cygwin compilers will do this for you by default; even if you run

```
g++ helloworld.cpp -o helloworld
```

it will generate an executable file named `helloworld.exe`.

I don't know what you did to create an executable file without the `.exe` extension. Whatever it was, don't do it again.

Comment: @return0: Out of curiosity, how exactly did you create an executable file named `helloworld` rather than `helloworld.exe`?